# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: regex, django, rest, mixins, serialization

**TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'**
In url.py, I am unable to mention the id object. The regex I have provided in ur_pattern, the browser unable to find the 'id'.

**url.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from withoutrest import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^api/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.EmployeeDetails.as_view()),
]
```

**view.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from withoutrest.models import employee
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from withoutrest.mixins import serializeMixin

# Create your views here.
class EmployeeDetails(serializeMixin,View):
    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        emp = employee.objects.get(id=id)
        json_data = self.serialize([emp,])
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

**mixins.py**:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json
class serializeMixin(object):
    def serialize(self, emp):
        json_data= serialize('json', emp)
        pdict= json.loads(json_data)
        list=[]
        for obj in pdict:
            emp_data=obj['fields']
            list.append(emp_data)
        json_data=json.dumps(list)
        return json_data
```

**test.py**:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
ENDPOINT = 'api/'


def get_resource(id):
    resp = requests.get(BASE_URL + ENDPOINT + id + '/')
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())
get_resource(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) instead of path.

Something like this:

```
re_path(r'^api/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetails.as_view()),
```

Comment: So when we have to use re-path and path?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Change your urls.py and import re_path

from django.urls import path, re_path
from withoutrest import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^api/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.EmployeeDetails.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: If it helps you to solve the issue, then accept the answer. So that  it can help others.